# How to distinguish as Linear or Non-linear constraints

Tags: optimization, matlab, constraints

In optimization problem $$\arg\max_{\substack{l_1 \in [0, 1],\cdots,l_{M} \in [0,1]}} T$$ I have $m=1\cdots,M$ constraints such that 
$$\ln \left[a_m\right] + \ln \left[ \left(\frac{l_m}{l_m + \sigma_m}\right) \right] +  \sum \limits_{i=1}^{m-1} {\ln \left[\left(1-l_i\right)\right]} \geq T$$ where $\sigma_m,~a_m>0$.

In MATLAB, I will use `fmincon` function.

How do I need to treat above constraints, e.g., as linear or non-linear constraints? It is important because if they are non-linear, I may need gradient equations as well.

Please help me, and thanks !!!

Comment: Well, is $\ln$ which acts on your decision variables a linear function?...

Comment: That is what I want to know whether this type of constraint is a linear or non-linear when $\sigma_m$ and $a_m$ are known constants.

Comment: Your decision variable is $l$, hence the constraints are by definition non-linear, as you apply nonlinear operations on those (divisions, logarithms).

Comment: Thanks @Johan, I may need gradient of each constraint then.